# NIC prob - "Unable to determine IP address from host name"

Tags: iis, localhost

So my problem is about that i cant go on my website on local, using IIS, while im connected to the internet.
In other words: I got this error message:

> The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://admin.mywebsite.loc/.../*.cfm
>
> > **Unable to determine IP address from host name "admin.mywebsite.loc"**
>
> The DNS server returned:
>
> > Name Error: The domain name does not exist.
>
> This means that the cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. Check if the address is correct.
>
> Your cache administrator is cachemaster@*.fr

But when I disable my Network Interface Card (no more internet) and then reload the page, it works perfectly. Kinda boring to enable/disable the NIC constantly. So i guess there's something going on with the network.

I tried one thing: my IPv6 was sending a response ::1, I found a lil' tuto, so I changed one line in my hosts file in '...\System32\drivers\etc\'. Then when I type 'ping localhost' in the console i get 127.0.0.1 but even after that it was still not working.

I'm open to any question that will help you helping me. Thanks a lot.